# PHP/MYSQL Prevent sql injection attacks function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, sql-injection

I want to upgrade and make more systematic, my protection against sql injection attacks.  I gather the three main methods are pdo, prepared statements and mysql_escape_string, that pdo is considered best but mysql_escape_string considered adequate if you are meticulous.  I don't think I am ready to go to PDO or prepared statements as I have a lot of complicated queries involving multiple tables so this would be a huge task.  But I want to make use of mysql_escape_string more programmatic.

Rather than escape every individual variable that users submit, I was thinking of escape the SQL commands with a standard function that might require some modification to handle punctuation  Is this a sound approach or will escaping the whole query create problems-I do use apostrophes, backticks and %, for example.  It would seem that a standard function for every sql statement would be more systematic and standard than the variable by variable approach.  So question is what modifications to handle punctuation might be needed?  Also, is there anything else that ought to go into the function such as htmlspecialchars and strip_tags as I gather mysql_escape_string is not 100% complete?

Here is basic function.

```
function safe($sql) {
$safesql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
return $safesql;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, just use PDO.  It will be far less work, and safer.

Comment: That, or use ActiveRecord\Model

Comment: @user1260310 you can also create views table for security/prevention, if someone does a sql-injection will be restricted.

Comment: Seems like you cannot ask a question that challenges the conventional wisdom without getting downvoted.  It would be a lot better to have a single function to do this--even a complex one... But I guess we should not even contemplate something so revolutionary.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think I am ready to go to PDO or prepared statements as I have a lot of complicated queries involving multiple tables so this would be a huge task.

Huge? Perhaps. Worth the effort though.

> will escaping the whole query create problems

Yes. Your function will have no way of knowing if a piece of SQL is an injection attack or something you intended.

You have to escape *text* at the point where it is inserted into *SQL*. You can't insert text into SQL and then figure out which bit was SQL and which bit was text afterwards.

> is there anything else that ought to go into the function such as htmlspecialchars and strip_tags

`strip_tags` throws data away. I wouldn't use it.

Both `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` offer protection against unsafe data being inserted into an HTML document. Use them before inserting data into an HTML document, not before inserting data into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it work with the whole query is if you write your own SQL parser, and even then, you must try to magically *see*  which parts of the query is SQL injections. That's not possible so no, you cannot do this with the entire query at once.

Comment: Mike B, how do you tell from one single query if it contains SQL injections?

Comment: http://blog.php-security.org/archives/67-Heuristic-SQL-Injection-Detection-for-Suhosin.html .. again not recommended but certainly possible. OP isn't the first one to think of it. Plenty of projects have been focused on stopping SQL injection before it even gets to PHP or sometimes on the other side from PHP to t-SQL - think magic quotes done right. Unfortunately it's not easy and there are always exceptions.

Comment: Mike B, the most common SQL injection is putting `' OR '' = '` inside a password field to "g3tz r00t". If you cannot catch this you may just as well stop trying and use prepared statements (which *is* the ultimate solution to the problem!)

Comment: Absolutely, PDO/Paramed queries are the way to go (this question is dumb) :)

Comment: PDO may be the preferred way to go but from what I gather, an awful lot of code on the webdoesn't use it.  What percentage of php on the web do you think uses PDO?  It's a dumb question if there are still many opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you shouldn't be using `mysql_real_escape_string` around your whole query, only the string values you are using to build your query.

Example:

```
"Select Id from table where username ='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' limit 1";
```

Comment: So I can better understand, in your above example, what would be so bad about escaping the rest of the query ie Select id from table where username = ' and then 'limit 1.  Is there no way to preserve the apostrophes around $username?

Comment: There simply isn't any benefit in escaping the rest of the query.  The whole purpose of escaping a string is to prevent SQL injection on a variable, because it is possible in some cases to manipulate the value of that vairable (if it comes from a _GET or _POST parameter).  If you escape the whole query, it actually opens up the possibility of injection.  I'd suggest you read up a little more on mysql_real_escape_string (note the difference between your suggested function mysql_escape_string, which IS insecure).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you can safely assume that protecting your "complicated queries" on your own is much more complex and time-consuming than just using PDO, ActiveRecord or the likes. Additionally, you'll make your code more database-agnostic.

Answer (score -1):

I personally like the db-class the guys from phpBB have written. It's excellent, fast and pretty secure.